# Application received signal SIGSEGV (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, segmentation-fault

This is my app crash stack. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
Application received signal SIGSEGV
(null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x31a593ff  + 186
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39754963 objc_exception_throw + 30
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31a59307  + 106
    3   ITUGO                               0x83f59 ITUGO + 524121
    4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x39bc8d33 _sigtramp + 34
    5   ITUGO                               0x40759 ITUGO + 247641
    6   ITUGO                               0xe4c61 ITUGO + 920673
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39b6e793  + 10
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39b6e5db  + 22
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x39b71e45 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 228
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x31a2d1b1  + 1288
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x319a023d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x319a00c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x3557f33b GSEventRunModal + 74
    14  UIKit                               0x338bc2b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
    15  ITUGO                               0x8543 ITUGO + 17731
    16  ITUGO                               0x84f8 ITUGO + 17656
)
```

Comment: You just need to symbolicate and identify what e.g. `0x83f59 ITUGO + 524121` corresponds to - it should be pretty obvious at that point.

Comment: That, or look at the console log at the time of the crash.  That looks a lot like a range exception on a CF call or the like.  Usually, those things log.   As well, the exception itself should have been logged.

Comment: Can you paste your code and mention in which line it is happening??

Answer (score 0):

you  should find the xxx.app.dSYM  and use the dSYMTool

fill in the information such as :

CPU Type: armv7
Slide Address: 0x00004000
Base Address: 0x0008a000

you will know the crash bug